# Mimicking an excel pivot in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

Been a long time since I've been in the DB world as I'm now primarily a front end developer.

I have a sql db table that looks like this :

```
Email          | State           | Status
___________________________________________________

bob@email.com    Colorado          1
jim@email.com    North Carolina    2
sarah@email.com  Colorado          3
fred@email.com   North Carolina    2
```

I need a query that makes a table that looks like this :

```
State          | 1          | 2          | 3          | Total 
_________________________________________________________________ 
Colorado         1            0            1            2
North Carolina   0            2            0            2
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table

Comment: Could you try this by yourself before we help you ? If you have provide us the query with the output of the query and what the problem with the output is. Also provide after the output the desired ouput

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
State,
sum(case when Status=1 then 1 else 0 end) '1',
sum(case when Status=2 then 1 else 0 end) '2',
sum(case when Status=3 then 1 else 0 end) '3',
sum(case when Status>0 then 1 else 0 end) 'total'
from Your_Table
group by State
```